# Getting user drawn line returned to tool in python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I'm trying to have a user draw a line on the map and then use that line as the input to the fence diagram tool (3D). Code is below and I've tried it several different ways but just can't make sense of it. I can get the tools to allow the user to draw the line, but once the tool runs, it fails.
This is a script tool running in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.

Using this [help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) as guidance:

```
#variables defined above but excluded. 
#get input from user
#what to call the cross section
crossSectionName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if crossSectionName == '#' or not crossSectionName:
    crossSectionName = "CrossSection1" # provide a default value if unspecified

#What disstance to search from the line created by the user
Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Distance == '#' or not Distance:
    Distance = "50 Meters" # provide a default value if unspecified


#get user drawn line
def getParameterInfo():
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Cross Section Line",
            name="in_feature_set",
            datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        param1.value = crossSectionLineLyr


#check out extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

#create fence
arcpy.FenceDiagram_3d(getParameterInfo(), [fenceSurf1, fenceSurf2, fenceSurf3, fenceSurf4], (fenceout + "\\" + crossSectionName))

#check in extension
arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing Python script tool and Python Toolbox tool syntax.  I've not done it for a while but if you are trying to write a Python script tool then I think you need to use `arcpy.GetParameter()` and set your parameter type as Feature Set on the tool properties.

Comment: Wow, so I just removed the def statement and added it in as a getParameter() as suggested and that did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using [@PolyGeo's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274131/getting-user-drawn-line-returned-to-tool-in-python-script-tool?noredirect=1#comment437117_274131) I just made a minor chage and it worked.

The updated code is below:

```
#get input from user
#what to call the cross section
crossSectionName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if crossSectionName == '#' or not crossSectionName:
    crossSectionName = "CrossSection1" # provide a default value if unspecified

#Get the line from the user
userLine = arcpy.GetParameter(1)

#What disstance to search from the line created by the user
Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Distance == '#' or not Distance:
    Distance = "50 Meters" # provide a default value if unspecified

#check out extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

#create fence
arcpy.FenceDiagram_3d(userLine, [fenceSurf1, fenceSurf2, fenceSurf3, fenceSurf4], (fenceout + "\\" + crossSectionName))

#check in extension
arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")
```